# SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character (only in Firefox)

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, firefox

I'm trying to parse the data in the parameter to the database. In IE, Opera, chrome everything works. In Mozilla does not work, write error SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character

here's the code parsing:

```
$.getJSON("<?php echo JURI::base()?>ajax.php?get=1&param="+param,function(data){
                    if(data)
                    {

                buildPopup(data.member_from,data.member_amount);
                            //$("body #scorepopup").fadeIn("slow");
                        var ww = $(window).width();
                        var wh = $(window).height();
                        var spw = $("body #scorepopup").width();
                        var sph = $("body #scorepopup").height();
                        var spt = Math.round(wh/2-sph/2);
                        var spl =  Math.round(ww/2-spw/2);
                        $("body #scorepopup").css("top",0);
                        $("body #scorepopup").css("left",spl);
                        $("body #scorepopup").show();
                        $("body #scorepopup").animate({top:spt+"px"},600, 'easeOutBounce'); 

                    }
                }
)
```

Function BuildPopup

```
function buildPopup(member_from,member_amount){
            if($("body #scorepopup").length) {
                $("body #scorepopup").remove();
            }
            $("body").append('<div id="scorepopup"><div class="ds-point">'
                    +'<?php echo JText::_('STAN') ?>'
                    +'&nbsp;<b>'
                    +member_from
                    +'</b><br/>'
                    +'<?php echo JText::_('POINT') ?>'
                    +':&nbsp;<b>'
                    +member_amount
                    +'</b></div><div id="closescorepopup"></div></div>'
            );
        };
```

ResponseText from Google Chrome:

```
{"id":"89095","member_no":"89095","username_m":"00047","group_id":"1","dsgid":"31","user_id":"0","member_amount":"91","title":"\u041a\u043b\u0456\u0454\u043d\u0442 dsuser89095","first_name":"dsuser89095","last_name":"\u041a\u043b\u0456\u0454\u043d\u0442","address":"","zip_code":null,"city":null,"county":null,"country":null,"telephone1":"","telephone2":null,"fax":null,"email":"89095ds@ds.com.ua","website":null,"profession":null,"birth_date":"0000-00-00","additional_info":"\u041a\u043b\u0456\u0454\u043d\u0442","member_from":"2013-07-04","member_until":"0000-00-00","committee_info":null,"images":"","last_payment_date":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","suspended":"0","published":"1"}
```

ResponseText from Firefox:

```
п»ї{"id":"89095","member_no":"89095","username_m":"00047","group_id":"1","dsgid":"31","user_id":"0","member_amount":"91","title":"\u041a\u043b\u0456\u0454\u043d\u0442 dsuser89095","first_name":"dsuser89095","last_name":"\u041a\u043b\u0456\u0454\u043d\u0442","address":"","zip_code":null,"city":null,"county":null,"country":null,"telephone1":"","telephone2":null,"fax":null,"email":"89095ds@ds.com.ua","website":null,"profession":null,"birth_date":"0000-00-00","additional_info":"\u041a\u043b\u0456\u0454\u043d\u0442","member_from":"2013-07-04","member_until":"0000-00-00","committee_info":null,"images":"","last_payment_date":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","suspended":"0","published":"1"}
```

In response from Firefox in the beginning there s unreadable characters: п»ї

Where did they come from? Probably through them does not work in Firefox.
I will be glad of any help

Comment: "In response from Firefox" - isn't it the response from ajax.php?

Comment: Try hitting the api url directly in both browsers and see if it shows up there. then start looking at the response headers for differences in how the data's interpreted

Comment: @mishik, yes from ajax.php, but only in firefox

Comment: You seem to have a [byte order mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) in your `ajax.php` script. Remove it and everything should be fine.

Comment: It seems BOM characters are sent. Is your PHP file utf-8 and/or have utf-8 characters somewhere in it? If not, resave it to _ansi_. Addiotionally, check for strange spaces before `<php` tag.

Comment: @vlzvl alternatively, OP could use an editor that doesn't add (and hide) the BOM

Comment: @Phil, indeed. For example, in _notepad++_ one can save without a BOM by `Encode in ANSI`.